# how to use BETWEEN mysql function in codeigniter to get data between two dates

Tags: mysql

```
 $this->db->SELECT('*')
          ->WHERE('VendorId',5)
          ->WHERE("Date BETWEEN CAST(2014-08-04 AS Date) AND CAST(2014-08-04 AS Date)")
          ->FROM('report1');

       $query = $this->db->get();
       return  $query->result();
```

I am getting a blank page with that query.Please any help.I am using Codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are missing ' to wrap date value

```
WHERE("Date BETWEEN CAST('2014-08-04' AS Date) ...
```

[check this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) .